# Запись в новый столбец DataFrame обработанных данных из другого столбца данного DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется:

```py
data = pd.Series(['10UKA20WY', '12JND20BB001', '22FAK20AP001', '20UBA10GP004F'])
```

Надо обработать записи по шаблону: pattern = r'([0-2]+[0-9]+[U]+[A-Z]{2})'.
В новом Serias получаю результат с помощью кода:

```py
pattern = r'([0-2]+[0-9]+[U]+[A-Z]{2})'
data.str.findall(pattern)
```

Все хорошо, но как избавиться от символов"[ ]" и не могу понять, откуда они взялись:

```py
0    [10UKA]
1         []
2         []
3    [20UBA]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
In [5]: data.str.extract(pattern)
Out[5]:
       0
0  10UKA
1    NaN
2    NaN
3  20UBA
```

Comment: Спасибо, MaxU! В данном случае помогло!